# Set range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have set count1 = 34, which count1 will change every time when data is updated.
And I want to set range of it. I tried to do it like this:

```
Dim test1 As Range

Set test1 = Range(“D4”, “D” & count1)
```

Which I wanna do is to set range for (“D4:D34”) in this case as test1. But I’m not sure if this’s right. Thanks.

Comment: Did it work...?

Comment: Assuming you use normal quotation marks and not the curly ones you are using in your post, it should work. Why are you using curly quotes? Sometimes when you copy/paste things from other websites, or when you copy/paste from a Word document, they will be curly like that.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want something like this.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim test1 As Range
    Dim count1 As Long
    
    count1 = 34
    
    Set test1 = Range("D4", "D" & count1)
    
    MsgBox test1.Address
    
    'Release the range object at the end of the code
    Set test1 = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Dim test1 As Range
Set test1 = Range(“D4:D" & count1)
```